# HandlebarsJS : Get elements i of each array, then element j, etc.?

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

**Given a JSON such :**

```
{
"network": 
   [
    { "name": [ "John",   "Jill",  "June"  ] },
    { "town": [ "London", "Paris", "Tokyo" ] },
    { "age" : [ "35",     "24",    "14"    ] }
   ]
}
```

Sadly, my input data is in this format and I have to stick with this.

**Looking for a final HTML result such :**

```
<ul>
<li>John, London, is 35 years old.</li>
<li>Jill, Paris, is 24 years old.</li>
<li>June, Tokyo, is 14 years old.</li>
</ul>
```

( So it actually browse the JSON by index, kind of 0, then 1, then 2 :

```
<ul>
<li>{{name}}[0], {{town}}[0], is {{age}}[0] years old.</li>
<li>{{name}}[1], {{town}}[1], is {{age}}[1] years old.</li>
<li>{{name}}[2], {{town}}[2], is {{age}}[2] years old.</li>
</ul>
```

)

**Is there a native way, using handlebarsJS, to do a template something such :**

```
  {{#each network}}<li>{{name}}[i], {{town}}[i], is {{age}}[i] years old.</li>{{/each}}
```

**?**

Comment: I would've tried `{{name[i]}}` if at all…

Comment: Does `{{name[i]}}` works ? I didn't find such thing in http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: I don't know but I would at least have expected that the index argument needs to be inside `{{}}` syntax.

Comment: {{name[i]}} doesn't works. See: http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz/gER9M/178/

Comment: None of the answers was suitable for my project. Your is based on underscore, which is outside the handlebars / javascript range the question implicitely expect.

Comment: write some JavaScript to take your existing data and restructure it so that it can be passed to the Handlebars template system. when you get to your templating system your data should be ready for output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hugolpz, you'll want to restructure your data before you begin using your template.  templates aren't supposed to contain any sort of 'intelligence'.  templates are there for creating output.

```
<script>
    var original = { "network":[
        { "name": [ "John",   "Jill",  "June"  ] },
        { "town": [ "London", "Paris", "Tokyo" ] },
        { "age" : [ "35",     "24",    "14"    ] }
    ]}

    if(
        original.network[0]['name'].length != original.network[1]['town'].length && 
        original.network[0]['name'].length != original.network[2]['age'].length 
    ) {
        console.log( 'data is not uniform' );
        return false;
    } else {
        var dataLength = original.network[0]['name'].length;
    }

    var dataString = '{"users":[REPLACETHIS]}';
    var usersString = '';

    for( i=0; i < dataLength; i++ ){
        usersString+='{"name":"'+original.network[0]['name'][i]+'","town":"'+original.network[1]['town'][i]+'","age":"'+original.network[2]['age'][i]+'"}';
        if( i < dataLength-1 ){
            usersString+=',';
        }
    }

    dataString = dataString.replace('REPLACETHIS',usersString);
    data = $.parseJSON(dataString);
</script>
```

you can pass this restructured data to Handlebars for templating output

declare your template ...

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="user-tmpl">
{{#users}}
    <p>
        name : {{name}} <br />
        town : {{town}} <br />
        age : {{age}} <br />
    </p>
{{/users}}
</script>
```

and do your handlebar templating ...

```
<script>
    var source = $('#user-tmpl').html();
    var bars = Handlebars.compile(source);
    $("#target").html(bars(data));
</script>
```

once you have your data structured in a way that's consistent with what you want to output everything becomes pretty simple

Comment: I don't really need speed, code clarity is more interesting for me (begginner). Alike, I'am rather reluctant to add one more library of this single function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the {{key}}[index], just {{key}}, #each [Object] already loops over the object and does that behind the scenes. .

Comment: But notice he doesn't want to loop over the `friends` object, but from 0 to 2 and access those indices on the different properties of `friends`.

Comment: (note: I renamed `friends` into `network`). +Bergi is right, this is all my question.